# How can one show an object is ready for garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ECMAScript 6 introduces weak maps, which are implemented in Node.JS v0.11.3 with the flag `--harmony`.

Consider the following piece of code.

```
var weakMap = WeakMap();
var temp = {};
weakMap.set(temp, 'Save me!');
temp = {};
```

When the last line is executed, the string `'Save me!'` is ready for garbage collection. Can it be demonstrated with code that the string no longer has a chain of strong references leading to it from the current scope?

I know weak maps do not have iteration or a `size` property similar to maps. Does it mean that there is no way of knowing *a posteriori* that a given object is no longer accessible from the weak map?

Comment: If you're wondering if a `weakMap` can be used to track down memory leaks *(other strong references to your `temp` object that you forgot about)*, I'm going to go out on a limb, and say "no".

Comment: The only way to tell if an object can be reached via a chain of strong references is to follow all chains of strong references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because it doesn't make sense to do so. There's just no good way to ask if something is reachable if you can't reach it. If there were a function

```
isStronglyReachable(foo)
```

then how would you pass it an unreachable `foo`? There's no way to pass it a weak reference to `foo`, and if you pass `foo` directly, then you know it's strongly reachable because you just used a strong reference to it (and binding it to a parameter creates another strong reference or two). You could try something of the form

```
weakmap.isValueStronglyReachable(key)
```

but then you'd need a strong reference to the key, which would make the value strongly reachable. Even if you tried something of the form

```
weakmap.getArrayOfUnreachableKeys()
```

(which would make the returned objects reachable through the returned array), the runtime would have to run a full GC pass to figure out which values are unreachable - and if it's doing a GC pass, why wouldn't it just delete the entries for unreachable keys?